# Is there any difference between AES_128_CBC and AES_128_CBC_SHA algorithm?

Tags: .net, encryption, aes, labview, encryption-symmetric

Is there any difference between AES_128_CBC and AES_128_CBC_SHA algorithm? I have a client document which says AES_128_CBC_SHA algorithm for data encryption. could anybody can share some Library files (.net, C,C#) which does AES_128_CBC_SHA algorithm. I am using LabVIEW for data encryption.

My module will accept encrypted data in AES_128-CBC_SHA algorithm.

Comment: There are multiple ways how AES-128 with CBC mode can be combined with SHA1. You should find out how it is meant in your case. Do you have some example code? Have you tried to look into the source code of the library you're using to see how the two would differ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Labview why are you asking for a .net, C, C# library?
Why don't use a native Labview library?

[Here is](https://decibel.ni.com/content/blogs/viGods/2012/06/04/labview-advanced-encryption-standart-aes-library) a free one, whereas [this one](http://www.ni.com/gate/gb/GB_EVALTLKTENCRYPLVS/US) is sold by LVS Tools.

Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26049672/why-does-chrome-display-a-sha1-message-with-a-sha2-certificate) could be useful about AES_128_CBC + SHA